# Have shiny load from a file not named app.R

Tags: r, shiny

Does anyone know i it is possible to change the default file that shiny loads? 
I was hoping for a bit more flexibility than one file per directory.

Comment: In `shiny::runApp` documentation is says that argument `appDir` accepts: "An ‘.R’ file containing a Shiny application". Your question is a little bit unclear. How are you running/loading file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your setup.

#### Setup 1: Run app locally from a file

If you want to run an application locally (inside an interactive R session) you can use the command

```
shiny::shinyAppFile("path/to/my/appFile.R")
```

to load an application. The app file does not have to be named `app.R` in that case. Note however that with this approach all relative paths (for example image paths) will be resolved relative to your working directory rather than relative to the app's directory.

#### Setup 2: Run app on a server

If the app shold be run via shiny-server (or shinyapps.io) things are more complicated. In this case the server will expect the app to be defined either as `app.R` or `ui.R/server.R` in order to be loaded properly. The only workaround I am aware of here is to use `shinyAppFile` inside `app.R` but this might not be very useful in most situations.

#### Setup 3: Define the app as an object

You can also define an app as an R object and invoke it by printing the object.

```
someAppObj <- shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(), server = function(...) {})

## start the app by printing it
someAppObj
```

As mentioned in the answer of @ismirsehregal, you can also use `runApp` instead of the printing method which will take care if relative paths and handle the app-environment slightly differently.

```
runApp(someAppObj)
```

Setup 1 is actually related to setup 3 since since `shinyAppFile` returns an app-object.

Answer (score 1):

For a single file app just rename it and add

```
app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app)
```

to be able to source it.