Deploying a Shiny App, using deployApp call
This code to upload my "Hello World" shiny App to ShinyApps.io works:
rsconnect::deployApp(account = 'richardrogers', appDir = "*********************************************/SuperSimpleShiny", appFiles = c("app.R", "config.yml"))

I receive this as a response:
-- Preparing for deployment ------------------------------------------------------------
v Re-deploying "supersimpleshiny" using "server: shinyapps.io / username: richardrogers"
i Looking up application with id "12017803"...
v Found application <https://richardrogers.shinyapps.io/supersimpleshiny/>
i Bundling 2 files: app.R and config.yml
i Capturing R dependencies with renv
v Found 30 dependencies
v Created 18,284b bundle
i Uploading bundle...
v Uploaded bundle with id 8625650
-- Deploying to server -----------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for task: 1417136163
  building: Building image: 10503736
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 10503736
  deploying: Starting instances
  rollforward: Activating new instances
  unstaging: Stopping old instances
-- Deployment complete -----------------------------------------------------------------
v Successfully deployed to <https://richardrogers.shinyapps.io/supersimpleshiny/>

I make only one change to the deployApp call, changing "app.R" to "SuperSimpleShiny.R":
rsconnect::deployApp(account = 'richardrogers', appDir = "*********************************************/SuperSimpleShiny", appFiles = c("SuperSimpleShiny.R", "config.yml"))

I receive this as a response:
-- Preparing for deployment ------------------------------------------------------------
v Re-deploying "supersimpleshiny" using "server: shinyapps.io / username: richardrogers"
Error in `quartoInspect()`:
! `quarto` not found.
i Check that it is installed and available on your `PATH`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I get the exact same results whether I execute these commands in RStudio or the standalone R Console.
I have used the fc (file compare) command line utility to compare "app.R", and "SuperSimpleShiny.R", and they are identical.
There must be some special significance of the file name "app.R".
Is it similar to the "C" main() function?
I've looked at similar posts about this problem, including this one:
r shinyapps deployment error when doing it manually
Maybe I've found a bug in the rsconnect::deployApp() function.
I'm stumped.
Any pointers most appreciated.
Richard

I can't remember where it is documented, but you definitely need to upload either an app.R or server.R and ui.R files for things to run on shinyapps.io. There are some workarounds in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022176/have-shiny-load-from-a-file-not-named-app-r

Very much appreciated!!!
